# Struggling to resolve "a float is required error" in python

Tags: python, minecraft

New Python user here, trying to develop my skills hacking Minecraft Pi. My current project is to set a block somewhere in the minecraft world with co-ordinates provided by the user in the terminal. I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/projects/blockInput.py", line 12, in <module>
        mc.setBlock(x,y,z,blockType)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mcpi/minecraft.py", line 138, in setBlock
        self.conn.send("world.setBlock", intFloor(args))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mcpi/minecraft.py", line 22, in intFloor
        return [int(math.floor(x)) for x in flatten(args)]
TypeError: a float is required
```

I assumed it was because the user was inputting integers, and amended my code, but I get the same error. Unfortunately most of the error means nothing to me. Can someone please help me understand the error as I'm not sure it means what I think it does?

My current code is below:

```
#connect to minecraft
import mcpi.minecraft as minecraft
mc = minecraft.Minecraft.create()

#mc.postToChat("Hello Minecraft World")

x = float(raw_input("Provide position x:"))
y = float(raw_input("Provide position y:"))
z = float(raw_input("Provide position z:"))
blockType = raw_input("Provide the block ID:")

mc.setBlock(x,y,z,blockType)
```

Comment: I think `blockType` should be an `int`.

Comment: So I amended:

    blockType = int(raw_input("Provide the blockID:"))

And it worked! Thank you, but how did you know this was the issue? I'm trying to learn how to read my error codes better.

Comment: I found mcpi's source code on github, found the `minecraft.py` file which is mentioned in the traceback, and had a look at the `setBlock` function. Admittedly, I did all this after I posted my comment; but 3 of your 4 variables _are_ floats, so the culprit was pretty obvious.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ClaireDodd! This is a _great_ first question, with a full minimal working example _and_ a traceback, try to put this much effort into all future ones too! Don't forget to accept an answer if it answers your question, it essentially marks it closed for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is visible in your traceback. Usually the last line contains the culprit, while the previous lines show how you got there:

```
return [int(math.floor(x)) for x in flatten(args)]
TypeError: a float is required
```

So it looks like a function is failing (with a `TypeError`) because it expects a float. What function could that be? Looking inside your list comprehension, I see `math.floor`. We can test this function and give it something that is not a float and hope it fails:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor(5)
5.0
```

Well that worked (unfortunately). Let's try something else:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.floor("5")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: a float is required
```

Ah ha! It looks like you are feeding it a string. Indeed, when you look at your code, you'll see your input comes from `raw_input`. This function isn't smart enough to know that "5" -> 5, you have to *cast* the variable to the correct type.